# Can NPM install the .git folder for dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

Using npm link to update dependencies during development is kind of a pain.

Does NPM have the equivalent of Composer's "--prefer-source" option to install dependencies as a version control repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No

> Git repos are never cloned directly into your application. They always
> follow this process:
>
> 1. npm does a bare clone of the repo into $TMPDIR
> 2. npm clones that clone into a directory in your npm cache, and then checks out the treeish that the branch requested mapped to.
> 3. npm produces an installable package tarball from that checkout that is then placed into your npm cache.
> 4. that cached tarball is installed into your application.
>
> If you
> want to be working directly from the Git checkout of your project,
> with all its submodules intact, your best bet is probably to npm link
> for the project with the submodules, and then npm link 
> it into the package consuming it. It's more unwieldy than using Git
> URLs in your package.json, but it will give you the control you need
> about how files are laid out.

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6700#issuecomment-71302066

Feature request for npm at Github for this feature: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7375

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is [npmgitdev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmgitdev). This is a wrapper which lets you work directly with git repos inside `node_modules`.

Answer (score -1):

you can add your dependencies as links to git like this:

"foo" : "git+https://git.server.host/bar/baz.git#master"

[see the docs for more information](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#Git-URLs-as-Dependencies)

Comment: this still loses the .git folder